# MPMoviePlayerController: key frame issue

Tags: iphone, macos, ipad, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a MPMoviePlayerController in my project.
Documentation says that next call:

```
moviePlayer.initialPlaybackTime = time;
```

starts at the closest key frame prior to the provided time.
Is it possible to start playing video from the specified time (not from the nearest key frame)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it really isn't.  Temporally compressed video streams can only generally start playback on a keyframe, as inter-frames depend on the keyframe for rendering.  If seekability is important to you, consider making files with smaller keyframe intervals.

Comment: 'consider making files with smaller keyframe intervals.' do you know of any way to do that?

Comment: When you actually go to encode your video, there's typically a keyframe interval setting on the encoder itself.  It may be one every certain number of seconds, or maybe the number of frames between keyframes.  They might also call it an I-frame instead of a keyframe.  But basically, you have to do this in your video encoder.

If the content is already encoded, then your only real option is to re-encode the content.